# Благодарствуйте

Tags: значение-слов

В прежние времена человек низшего сословия, обращаясь к представителю высшего, благодаря его за что-либо, говорил "благодарствуйте", а не "благодарствую". Впрочем, кажется, и второе бывало, но чаще всё-таки первое. Почему?

Comment: Так ведь разницы-то особой и нету. Дарить и дарствовать - синонимы. Второе устарело.

Comment: Ну как нету... Мне сделали доброе дело – и я благодарю, благодарствую, это понятно. А вот "благодарствуйте" – непонятно.

Comment: А... Вы так это понимаете. Смена объекта - субъекта. ну не знаю. Тогда это к Славе с его источником. Мне лично такое объяснение кажется несколько наивным, но если встать на Ваши позиции, то оно приемлемо.

Comment: благодарствуйте, это ответ на добрые действия лица с которым на Вы. Или просто "благодарю Вас"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этимологические словари (И Фасмер тоже) говорят, что *благода́рствуй* сокращено из *благодарствую* - «приношу благодарение». То есть *благодарствуй* - это разговорный, сокращённый вариант простого люда, а дальше по аналогии: *помилуй-помилуйте, пожалуй-пожалуйте* - вежливая форма, обращённая к уважаемому человеку, приобретает множ. число. А смысл не меняется - "приношу благодарение", только не тебе, а Вам. А уже позже от них - благодарю. Форма упрощается, как, собственно, и весь язык.

Answer (score 4):

"благодарствуйте" пошло от

[***"благодарствую тя, Господи"***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=5Y6gCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&dq=%22%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CEEQ6AEwB2oVChMIjY3Mobn3yAIVwXNyCh2qQAFr#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5%22%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C&f=false)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот это да, никогда бы не подумал. Благодарствуйте. Это Даль? ))

Comment: Не Даль. **Григорий Дьяченко** (по ссылке в моём ответе пройдите).

Comment: Ну да, конечно.  Не иначе как "тя, Господи"...  Чего ещё от церковного словаря ожидать?  То есть прот. Дьяченко утверждает, что "багодарствуйте" произошло от "благодарю".

Answer (score 0):

"**Благодарствуйте**" - повелительное наклонение, аналогичное "пожалуйте" или "помилуйте".  Оно, хоть и называется, *повелительным*, является всё-таки больше "умоляющим" или "просительным".

С другой стороны, выражение "**благодарств*ую***" можно, по-видимому, интерпретировать как *благословение*, т.е. пожелание добра, блага, констатация факта доброго отношения просящего к тому, к кому тот обращался.

---

**Благодарствовать** = дарствовать (даровать, дарить) благо.

Кстати, ответом на действие, принесшее благо, у человека, которому это благо было сделано, было восклицание: "*Благодарствуете*!", то есть "[вы мне] **благо дарите** [своим поступком]".

Возможно, впоследствии акт *признания* хорошего дела получил это же наименование.  Если кто-то сказал: "**Благодарствуете**!", то про этого человека говорили, что он "*поблагодарствовал*".

Таким же рефлексивным манером постепенно это слово перекочевало в настоящее время.  Вместо того, чтобы говорить: "Вы мне **благодарствуете**", люди стали говорить: "***Я* благодарствую**" (т.е. "*Я признаю, что вы мне делаете добро*").

Ну, а потом это уже преобразовалось в "***благодарю***" и оригинальный смысл уже потеряло.

Comment: >> *"Благодарствуйте" - повелительное наклонение, аналогичное "пожалуйте" или "помилуйте". Оно, хоть и называется, повелительным, является всё-таки больше "умоляющим" или "просительным".* Так оно было именно выражением благодарности, а не "просительным".