# Дарю Вам и благодарю Вас — почему?

Tags: этимология

Почему в словосочетании *благодарю Вас* используется винительный падеж, тогда как в словосочетании *дарю Вам* - дательный?

Comment: Полезное — рядом: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419332/%d0%91%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5/443832#443832

Answer (score 1):

***Благодарить*** и ***дарить*** — **переходные** глаголы.

Дарить (что? кому?) благо Вам.

Но так как прямое дополнение ***благо*** вошло в состав глагола ***благодарить***, то в качестве прямого объекта стал использоваться бывший адресат: благодарить (кого?) Вас.

Управление в русском языке. Автор Д. Э. Розенталь.

ДАРИТЬ — 1. [давать в качестве подарка; отдавать безвозмездно] кому что. У черкесов есть очень милый обычай дарить гостю всё, что он похвалит (Купр.);

БЛАГОДАРИТЬ,  (кого-что). Выражать благодарность. Б. друзей.